# AWS Cognito Trigger Post Authenticated - Lambda Nodejs 8.10 - return custom response error TypeError: Cannot set property

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm trying do build a web application integrated with AWS Cognito.

When I create a lambda function, using Node.js 8.10, to return specific response object I get an error:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  event["response"] = {
        "test": "testing"
      }
  event.done(null, event);
};
```

The code is simple:

WebApp Login -> Cognito User Pool -> Post Authentication Trigger -> Lambda function.

What I need is that when Cognito Post Authentication Trigger calls the lambda Function, and returns a response with an object, that response gets back to the WebApp.

My Login Submit Handler is something like:

```
handleLoginSubmit = async event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.props.isLoading(true);

  if(this.validateForm()) {
    this.props.isLoading(false);
    return;
  }
  try {
    await Auth.signIn(this.state.email, this.state.password);
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then(user => {
        console.log("cognito return", user);
        this.props.userHasAuthenticated(true);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log("error: ",err));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error currentAuthenticatedUser: ', e);
    this.props.isLoading(false);
  }
}
```

Login works, ok.

But I can never retrieve my response.test that i'm trying to pass over.

How do I retrieve that response sent from lambda to Post Authentication trigger from Cognito?

Comment: Got it working  ?

Comment: @YogeshwarTanwar it is (or was when I tried) not possible.